# How to change the grid's length values?

Tags: units

I have a model of a gear that should be in the millimeters but when I scale it to that size it becomes so small that I can't zoom in to see it. Right now the grid is in metric and each grid is 1m x 1m x 1m. But I want to change the grid so each square in the grid is 10mm x 10mm x 10mm.

Answer (score 10):

You have 3 options essentially.

Two of which are cosmetic, and involve changing the grid size - but will not affect actual scale or unit measurements of your file for 3D printing or other CAM methods.
[image: Cosmetics]

By default, 1 blender unit (and 1 grid unit) equals 1 meter. If you want to 1 blender unit to equal 1mm, you can either:
Option 1 - scale the grid via the Properties Panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) --> Display --> Grid Floor Scale.

Option 2 - In the Properties Window --> Scene settings --> Units, 1st set to Metric, then set the scale to 0.001.

However, if you export or save your file, 1 blender unit will still equal 1mm for most external programs.

If you want to print your model, your safest bet will be to scale your model and regard your model's dimensions as if they are in millimeters. For instance, 155 blender units = 15.5cm.

Of course you can scale your model AND change the grid settings to make the grid nicer, no contradiction there.

Comment: Would it also be possible to set 1 blender unit to equal, say, 4mm? I am working with wood with a thickness of 4mm. The parts will be cut from this wood later on.