# Change grid size in blender 2.80 beta?

Tags: snapping, scale, tilesize

In older versions the way is the
[following](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbWED.jpg&imgrefurl=https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40224/how-to-change-the-grids-length-values&h=815&w=1007&tbnid=KkBXkULgOYgHuM:&q=blender%20grid%20size&tbnh=160&tbnw=198&usg=AI4_-kSxvMPsODZbNdDYbUZvxpL8ulpIHw&vet=12ahUKEwiZ8_6Q18nfAhVy_SoKHb11CbsQ9QEwAHoECAkQBg..i&docid=AxYbX9RFw2kOZM&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ8_6Q18nfAhVy_SoKHb11CbsQ9QEwAHoECAkQBg)

But in 2.80 beta by default there is no even option "Display" which should contain "Scale".

So how to find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will find the grid scale options in the Overlay panel.

[image]