# Grid size missing in 2.80.75?

Tags: snapping

According to [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/127506/65252) answer, it should be located in overlays:

[image]

But I don't see it there:

[image]

Where can I change grid size?

Edit: It seems this bug (or feature?) manifests only in Quad View. In other views it works fine (any changes are only for the view on which changes are being made, so by changing it in a classic "3D viewport" does nothing in other viewports including the quad one).

Comment: It's there for me in 2.80.75. Can you check if it appears in a new project?

Comment: @rjg Nope, it's not in a freshly created project as well :(.